# What configuration is necessary for Amazon s3 and CORS?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

As far as I am able to tell, the only configuration which should be necessary to get s3 to return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is setting a CORS policy and sending the `Origin` header.

Here is my CORS policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

When I send this request:

```
GET /dots.png HTTP/1.1
Host: dta-test.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin: https://www.test.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I get a response with these headers:

```
Accept-Ranges →bytes
Cache-Control →public
Content-Length →893
Content-Type →image/png
Date →Thu, 09 Jan 2014 22:27:20 GMT
ETag →"5345e98a3abcb1057d1a427551d8d702"
Last-Modified →Thu, 09 Jan 2014 19:27:56 GMT
Server →AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2 →2AFNGowXCkLUJa09ZNERXqzxn5IwnygTKCXut0m0gvpapjxXn/kAPYQNvv4pYvVy
x-amz-request-id →71B183AF938A075D
```

As far as I am aware, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be included in this response.  What am I missing?

**Edit:**

This is what I'm missing: I was using the Postman Chrome extension.  Chrome sanitizes the Origin header when making requests, even from extensions.  It throws the error `Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"`, which I missed.

We can see with curl that this is actually working:

```
curl -H "Origin: https://www.test.com" -I "https://dta-test.s3.amazonaws.com/dots.png" -s
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: NnRAOdCOpMCtZ8Jk1bpnuRASb0K/gzM0Vv/6D28C6grcbEZoe2OC0cuu3SMwDaXe
x-amz-request-id: 70110890812CAC58
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 23:03:41 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Cache-Control: public
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 19:27:56 GMT
ETag: "5345e98a3abcb1057d1a427551d8d702"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 893
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: If you are not receiving an ACAO header in the response, then your request does not contain an Origin header.  You will need to take a closer look at your request.  I'm not sure how you are examining the headers.

Comment: I am using the Postman Chrome extension.

Comment: If you are artificially adding the Origin header via Postman, Chrome will ignore this.  If you open up dev tools, you will likely see that the actual request sent does not contain an Origin header.